# 3ds max wont weld vertices of poly made from shape

Tags: vertex, 3dsmax, vertices, 3ds, poly

So I have tried to make a glass panel of car headlight by caping, extruding and so on. It didnt work, so I have created a spline from shape I need and somehow turned it into poly and now I am trying to weld vertices to the base. It doesnt work. Faces are flipped right way, object is attached back to base. Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After you turn your spline to mesh you need to extrude the back face and delete it so you will be able to attach both objects together. Note that both object main faces should be deleted so you can weld vertices together. send a screenshot to see more details.